# Replace nodes in double linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Given two double linked lists I'm supposed to change, not just the elements, but the nodes of one of the lists so that the sum in the same positions equals a certain number.

```
public void repair(int num){
    Node list1 = head1;
    Node right = head2;

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        int element = num - list1.element;
        Node p = right.previous;
        Node s = right.next;
        right = new Node(element, null, null);

        p.next = right;
        right.previous = p;
        right.next = s;
        s.previous = right;

        list1 = list1.next;
        right = right.next;
    }
}
```

size = size of both list which is the same.
I've tried a lot of things but it always gives me nullpointerexception on p.next = right and s.previous = right;

I don't understand why it gives me this error. Can someone explain and show me a way of solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means p is `null`

```
Node p = right.previous;
```

Must be returning `null`

Seeing as `right` is defined as `head2`, you will have to look into head 2 and work out why `head2.previous` is null. I guess it is the beginning of the list or something.

You need to put null checks in so you only run operations on next / previous nodes when they are not null.